# Tool/Parser for preprocessor #if statements?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, preprocessor

I am working on many C-sourcecode files which contain many preprocessor `#if`, `#elseif` and `#else` statements.

This statements often check for a `#define`, e.g.

```
#if(Switch_TestMode == Switch_TestModeON)
/* code 1 */
#else
/*code 2 */
#endif
```

Often this preprocessor statements are located within c-if statements which makes the sourcecode nearly unreadable for human beeings.

The `#define`s used for this preprocessor `#if` statements are defined within an extra file.

My idea now is to have a tool which checks this `#define`d switch settings and then only copies the lines of sourcecode which apply using the current #defines/switch settings.

For the above example I would like to get a new .c file which contains only

```
/*code 2 */
```

assumed the `#define` of `Switch_TestMode` is not equal to `Switch_TestModeON`.

Are there tools (freeware || low-cost) available which do this job?
Or do I have to write my own preprocessor parser for this?

(It is impossible for me to run the compiler using a special parameter which does this job, because our company is creating the C-sourcecode, another company is compiling.)

Thanks for any hint!

Regards

Thomas

Comment: Few things to consider/explore: if your client reports compilation error line numbers they'll be harder to map back to your original sources.  Preprocessors typically put some markup in their output so the compiler can provide useful line numbers, but I'm not aware of this being standardised between compilers so you may not be able to markup your output suitably for your clients' compilers.

Answer (score 4):

unifdef is available from http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/.

Comment: This tool has very nice coding style and extremely easy compilation (no automake, just a simple makefile, and also a solution for Visual Studio on Windows). Its simplicity charmed me...

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sunifdef](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sunifdef/)

Edit: Which has now become [Coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the GNU compiler using command line option -E to do the preprocessing.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP is asking for because this will also cause other preprocessing directives and macro invocations to be evaluated.

Comment: Op said, "lines of sourcecode which apply using the current #defines/switch settings".  If he meant a partial set, he could have said so.  Agreed, the Sunifdef answer is better if he only wants to remove *some* of conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unifdef.