# selective preprocessing of #ifdefs in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have large .c and .h files from which i have to select only preprocessors directives satisfying these conditions as below

`#if(VALUE==5) ||(VALUE==6)`

Rest of  preprocessors directives should remain untouched.I have already looked into `unifdef` and `sunifdef` they will allow me to identify `#if` and `#ifdef` but i want to chose selectively not all `#if`, `#ifdefs`. Is there a utility thats allows me to give, e.g., `VALUE==5` and chose only those?

Basically I need preprocessor directives selection based on my input value.

Comment: what do you want to do? remove this directives? get the code between them? just print the lines containing them? get the line numbers?

Comment: Basically i need to identify them and even get the lines of code between them.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4092448/700170 may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try Running the Script, it will print the lines of code and code present inside the #if block.
This only scans the file statically. You can give it a try.

```
# ./run.sh filename "String to search in if"
# example ./run.sh test.h "#if VALUE"

# Get the line number of Searching string locations
# store it in a file
awk "/$2/{ print NR }" $1 > temp_if

# to store total lines present inside the if contruct
totalLinesCount=0

# read one line at a time, that is go through one occurance of string at a time
while read matchLineNum
do
    printf "Match Found in line number $matchLineNum\n"
    #search for first occurance of #elif from the matched string.
    elifLineNum=$(tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | awk "/#elif/{ print NR;exit }")
    if [ "$elifLineNum" == "" ]
    then
        # if not found set it to some high value
        elifLineNum=$(wc -c $1)
    fi
    elseLineNum=$(tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | awk "/#else/{ print NR;exit }")
    if [ "$elseLineNum" == "" ]
    then
        elseLineNum=$(wc -c $1)
    fi
    endifLineNum=$(tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | awk "/#endif/{ print NR;exit }")

    # check if #endif / #elif / #else occurs first
    if [ $endifLineNum -lt $elseLineNum -a $endifLineNum -lt $elifLineNum ]
    then
        # store the code count
        totalLinesCount=$(expr $totalLinesCount + $(expr $endifLineNum - 1))
        # store the code
        tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | head -n $(expr $endifLineNum - 1) >> out

    elif [ $elseLineNum -lt $endifLineNum -a $elseLineNum -lt $elifLineNum ]
    then
        totalLinesCount=$(expr $totalLinesCount + $(expr $elseLineNum - 1))
        tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | head -n $(expr $elseLineNum - 1) >> out

    elif [ $elifLineNum -lt $elseLineNum -a $elifLineNum -lt $endifLineNum ]
    then
        totalLinesCount=$(expr $totalLinesCount + $(expr $elifLineNum - 1))
        tail -n +$(expr $matchLineNum + 1) $1 | head -n $(expr $elifLineNum - 1) >> out

    else
        printf "\n Error \n"
    fi
done < temp_if
printf "\nTotal number of lines present inside the given condition is $totalLinesCount\n"
rm -f temp_if
printf '\nFinal Extracted Out\n'
cat out
rm -f out
```

Comment: /usr/bin/run.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/run.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/run.sh: run.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
/usr/bin/run.sh: run.sh: line 34: `    elif [ $elseLineNum -lt $endifLineNum -a
'elseLineNum -lt $elifLineNum ]. Can you please help me with it.. I am in windows environment using cygwin to run this script

Comment: use dos2unix -ascii run.sh test.h, to convert the windows format to unix format, actually windows and unix have a different way of representing newline character in file. After converting the files run the script

Comment: I used the command you suggested and i can also confirm something is changing by seeing the last modified date of file after execution of that command. But still i am getting same error.. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Thanks for all help..I have written my own utility to do this since none of the existing solutions helped me.